# unable to save upload file name to SQL in PHP

Tags: php, sql, upload

Am using below code to upload multiple images and Rename, compress, create thumbnail image with below code everything is fine but upload file name doesnt saves to SQL,

Can some one help to find whats wrong in code\

```
<?php
require('includes/config.php');
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $newname = md5(rand() * time());
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $uploadedFiles = array();
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
            $errors = array();
            $file_name = md5(uniqid("") . time());
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
            if ($file_type == "image/gif") {
                $sExt = ".gif";
            } elseif ($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg") {
                $sExt = ".jpg";
            } elseif ($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png") {
                $sExt = ".png";
            }
            if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif', '.jpg', '.png'))) {
                $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
            }
            if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
                $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
            }
            $desired_dir = "upload/";
            if (empty($errors)) {
                if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);
                }
                if (move_uploaded_file(compress_image($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt, 50))) {
                    $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($file_name . $sExt, 1);
                } else {
                    echo "Couldn't upload file " . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
                    $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($_FILES['files']['name'][$key], 0);
                }
            } else {

            }
        }
        foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
            if (!empty($row[1])) {
                $codestr = '$file' . ($key + 1) . ' = $row[0];';
                eval($codestr);
            } else {
                $codestr = '$file' . ($key + 1) . ' = NULL;';
                eval($codestr);
            }
        }
    }
    $orig_directory = "$desired_dir";
    $thumb_directory = "upload/thumb/";
    $dir_handle = opendir($orig_directory);
    if ($dir_handle > 1) {
        $allowed_types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
        $file_type = array();
        $ext = '';
        $title = '';
        $i = 0;
        while ($file_name = readdir($dir_handle)) {
            if ($file_name == '.' || $file_name == '..') {
                continue;
            }
            $file_type = \explode('.', $file_name);
            $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_type));
            $title1 = implode('.', $file_type);
            $title = htmlspecialchars($title1);
            if (in_array($ext, $allowed_types)) {
                $nw = 250;
                $nh = 180;
                $source = "$desired_dir{$file_name}";
                $stype1 = explode(".", $source);
                $stype = $stype1[count($stype1) - 1];
                $dest = "upload/thumb/{$file_name}";
                $size = getimagesize($source);
                $w = $size[0];
                $h = $size[1];
                switch ($stype) {
                    case 'gif':
                        $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                        break;
                    case 'jpg':
                        $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                        break;
                    case 'png':
                        $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                        break;
                }
                $dimg = resizePreservingAspectRatio($simg, $nw, $nh);
                imagepng($dimg, $dest);
            }
        }closedir($dir_handle);
    }
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO allpostdata(apdtitle, apdcategory, apdsubcategory, brand, model, driven, mobscat, mbrand, mmodel, ecate, ebrand, reoption, bhk, sfeet, jcategory, jobtype, scatergory, pcategory, ecategory, gender, notcate, posted, usernme, view, location, pnumber, prodprice, apddescription, img1, img2, img3, img4)"
            . " VALUES (:apdtitle, :apdcategory, :apdsubcategory, :brand, :model, :driven, :mobscat, :mbrand, :mmodel, :ecate, :ebrand, :reoption, :bhk, :sfeet, :jcategory, :jobtype, :scatergory, :pcategory, :ecategory, :gender, :notcate, :posted, :usernme, :view, :location, :pnumber, :prodprice, :apddescription, :img1, :img2, :img3, :img4)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':apdtitle', $apdtitle, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apdcategory', $apdcategory, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apdsubcategory', $apdsubcategory, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':brand', $brand, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':model', $model, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':driven', $driven, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':mobscat', $mobscat, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':mbrand', $mbrand, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':mmodel', $mmodel, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ecate', $ecate, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ebrand', $ebrand, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':reoption', $reoption, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':bhk', $bhk, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sfeet', $sfeet, PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
    $stmt->bindParam(':jcategory', $jcategory, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':jobtype', $jobtype, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':scatergory', $scatergory, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pcategory', $pcategory, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ecategory', $ecategory, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gender', $gender, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':notcate', $notcate, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':posted', $added_on, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':usernme', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':view', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pnumber', $pnumber, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':prodprice', $prodprice, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apddescription', $apddescription, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img1', $file1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img2', $file2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img3', $file3, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img4', $file4, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }exit;
}
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) { 
    $info = getimagesize($source_url); 
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpg') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
    }

    imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality); 

    return $destination_url; 
} 
function resizePreservingAspectRatio($img, $targetWidth, $targetHeight) {
    $srcWidth = imagesx($img);
    $srcHeight = imagesy($img);
    $srcRatio = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;
    $targetRatio = $targetWidth / $targetHeight;
    if (($srcWidth <= $targetWidth) && ($srcHeight <= $targetHeight)) {
        $imgTargetWidth = $srcWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = $srcHeight;
    } else if ($targetRatio > $srcRatio) {
        $imgTargetWidth = (int) ($targetHeight * $srcRatio);
        $imgTargetHeight = $targetHeight;
    } else {
        $imgTargetWidth = $targetWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = (int) ($targetWidth / $srcRatio);
    }
    $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
    $targetTransparent = imagecolorallocate($targetImg, 255, 0, 255);
    imagefill($targetImg, 0, 0, $targetTransparent);
    imagecolortransparent($targetImg, $targetTransparent);
    imagecopyresampled($targetImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);
    return $targetImg;
}
?>
```

**PHP Error Log**

```
[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefrompng(): 'upload/26745882e73c3148b2c3cbc9d73b67d1.png' is not a valid PNG file in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 117

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. imagecreatefrompng() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:117

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 180

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. imagesx() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:180

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 181

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. imagesy() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:181

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  Division by zero in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 182

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 198

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:25 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. imagecopyresampled() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:198

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefrompng(): 'upload/419785bf8a7d56c9a869f77b909989dd.png' is not a valid PNG file in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 117

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. imagecreatefrompng() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:117

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 180

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. imagesx() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:180

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 181

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. imagesy() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:181

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  Division by zero in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 182

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 198

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:22:50 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. imagecopyresampled() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:198

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefrompng(): 'upload/7d64d4edebe88b16d3285b1bde173c23.png' is not a valid PNG file in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 117

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. imagecreatefrompng() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:117

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 180

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. imagesx() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:180

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 181

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. imagesy() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:181

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  Division by zero in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 182

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 198

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:17 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. imagecopyresampled() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:198

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefrompng(): 'upload/ee1b337a631f0c99704a2e2dfbd5667d.png' is not a valid PNG file in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 117

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. imagecreatefrompng() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:117

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 180

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. imagesx() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:180

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 181

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. imagesy() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:181

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  Division by zero in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 182

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning:  imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 198

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:0

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. resizePreservingAspectRatio() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:120

[14-Jun-2018 11:23:41 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. imagecopyresampled() C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php:198
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: i don't get error everything works fine but file name are not saved to Database(SQL)

Comment: For starters I do not see where file1 through file4 are set.

Comment: i have `foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
            if (!empty($row[1])) {
                $codestr = '$file' . ($key + 1) . ' = $row[0];';
                eval($codestr);
            } else {
                $codestr = '$file' . ($key + 1) . ' = NULL;';
                eval($codestr);
            }
        }`

Comment: Place a debugger after this for-each loop and check if the variables are getting value properly or not. Looks like the input for this loop doesn't has values and hence the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: @Joseph_J check out my question ADD error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATED***

The PHP GD library offers several functions to create an image object/resource. The names are easy enough to follow `imagecreatefromjpeg()`, `imagecreatefrompng()`, ect...These do however require that you are feeding the functions the correct image type otherwise they will most likely fail or be problematic. By the way there is not a native function for bitmaps.  On php.net a guy wrote a really good function for `imaagecreatefrombmp()`.

There is also another function called `imagecreatefromstring()`.  This is the only one that I use.  This function will also return false if it fails to generate an object from the string, hence there was a problem with the image.

```
$source = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file));

if($source){

 //Do something with your image.  This is where you will do some additional checks for dimensions and for mime-type.

} else{

echo 'There was an error with your image.';

}
```

As for all you errors.  They are a result of not creating a valid image object/resource.

From your list of errors:

- `createimagefrompng()` - This is because the image is not png or you do not have the correct path to the image.  Make sure you check that the file exist on the path you are using.  Use `imagecreatefromstring()` instead.
- `imagesx()` & `imagesy()` - These both require an image resource  as there paremeter.  You get an image resource from using the `imagecreatefromstring()` function.
- `imagecopyresamped()` - The second parameter needs to be a resource.  Again, use the `imagecreatefromstring()` to generate the resource.

Also, this is important.  Make sure you are destroying your image resources after your done with them.  They consume a large amount of memory quickly.

`imagedestroy($resource)`

Your code was probably not even getting to your query due to all the errors.

Fix all of these and then if you still can't figure it out post another question with your latest code.

Comment: i get multiple error `imagecreatefrompng()` `imagesx()``imagesy()` `Division by zero in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 187`  `Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Classfied\add_listing.php on line 203`

Comment: So all of those errors you just posted are not related to your query.  I thought that you were not getting any errors and that your query was the issue.

Comment: i made change to code as you said, once making changes i get theses error, befor there were no error